# How to animate cutting of a curve?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

I have an array of molecules along a curve which makes the DNA model.
How can I show the cutting of the DNA like what is shown below.

I want to show the DNA get cuts and moves apart like this.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would do 2 arrays and where they meet there is obviously already a cut. Then just animate the curve seperating.

If you want the ends of the curve being connected you can give the ends vertices a hook and place the 2 hooks on the same spot. Then you can set one as a parent and if you now move the parent hook it will seem like they are connected.

Hopefully I could help you.